# How to keep form's values when doing a redirect

Tags: laravel, forms, redirect

I'm doing a static website using Laravel 5.6, which means there is no asynchronous requests to my server. In my website at **/users/create**, I have a form to add a new user.

When there are errors in the fields of this form, `UserController` redirects to the same address, **/users/create**, but with flash data to print that there is an error:

```
return redirect('/users/create')->with(['status' => 'Errors in the form.']);
```

But the problem is that I lost all the data of the form when doing that. Is there a simple way to keep the form's data in my case?

The browser I want this feature to work is Firefox and/or Chrome. No need to bother for IE or any other browser. I noticed that when doing a refresh on these 2 browsers, the form's data is always preserved, and I wonder if I can use it for my website. Maybe there is a Laravel helper to do refresh requests with flash data?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: <input type="text" value="{{old('lastname')}}" name="lastname">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *UserController* you can use

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

and in your view retrieve old value

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

for more information you can visit official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input

**Update**

You can also set default value to old input

```
value="{{old('username', 'default_value')}}"
```

Comment: If old value is not defined, it doesn't trigger errors?

Comment: You can always check if value is defined or not *@if(isset('username') old('username') @endisset*